# I get a 502 bad gateway ONLY with a specific combination of domain/root folders - NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have a VPS running NGINX and virtual hosts, with a configuration such as this:

Domains directing to it:

```
lolpics.no
smscloud.no
idmag.no
```

Root folders:

```
/home/vds/www/lolpics
/home/vds/www/smscloud
/home/vds/www/idmag
```

SMSCloud.no is the site that keeps getting 502 errors, but if I make the domain direct to any of the other folders, the site works, or if I make any other domain name direct to the /home/vds/www/smscloud folder, it works.
Only smscloud.no with /home/vds/www/smscloud breaks

I tried putting this between the http{} in my nginx.conf and no help:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

**EDIT:**
Well, that was slightly silly, if anyone from Google stumbles on this, here's how I fixed it, I just added this to the http{}:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size  16k;
fastcgi_buffers      16  16k;
```

So that the start of my http block is:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    fastcgi_buffer_size  16k;
    fastcgi_buffers      16  16k;
```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Please could you submit your solution as an answer, so that others know that this is solved. Thanks.